# C# Is it possible to add new item to List of interface?

Tags: c#, interface

I'd like to ask if it is possible to add an item to a list of interface?
Example:

I have a list of interface:

```
List<ITestItem> testList = new List<ITestItem>();
```

I want to add a new item to that list. But I couldn't find a way to create a new instance from `ITestItem`.

Besides, there is no class that implements the interface `ITestItem`.

So, is there anyway to add a new item to `ITestItem`?

All I want is something like:

```
List<ITestItem> testList = new List<ITestItem>();
testList.Add(new ITestItem());
```

Thank you in advanced.

Note: my question is to ask if it is possible. If no, it's OK for me.

Comment: What do you expect to do with some random class created from this interface, what class is going to control the logic to the contract?

Comment: When there´s no class implementing the interface, what instances *does* your list contain? There´s no such thing as an interface-instance, as interfaces don´t have instances, they are just a *view* on an **existing** instance.. So if there´s no class implementing the interface you can´t create an instance and thuis you can´t add an instance of it. It´s not really clear to me what exactly you want to add to your list.

Comment: This question is becoming a graveyard of misunderstanding. please update your question with more details on why you need to `create a new instance from ITestItem` why do you need this, what are you going to do with it

Comment: @TheGeneral Which is why I´m voting to close this question as unclear.

Comment: @All: sorry all, I made a mistake. I found a class that implements the interface.

Comment: @Alex, why did you edit my question and remove the update part?

Comment: @anhtv13 because that should be an answer, not part of the question. The 'update' added nothing to the question.

Comment: @Alex then you should tell me to do it, not to modify the question without asking me.

Comment: @anhtv13 no, I just removed the irrelevant part of your question (the part which wasn't a question) Please read up on how Stackoverflow works. Your question is already closed because it was of poor quality any way.

Comment: @Alex you have enough reputation to do whatever you like. I don't know the answer so I just post it on this site. Don't expect everyone on this site are experts. If I already know the answer, then I don't waste my time here.

Comment: @anhtv13 i answered your question days ago! I just edited your question to remove irrelevant text from it. I'm not sure why we are still discussing this?!

Comment: If you think this question is poor quality, you should delete it.

Comment: @anhtv13 Please learn how StackOverflow works, and earn sufficient reputation to participate in moderation. All the best.

Comment: But when people ask questions, users like you just downvote their questions, probably to prevent other users from getting enough reputation.

Comment: @anhtv13 i didn't downvote your question, i ANSWERED your question, but you're giving me a hard time!

Answer (score 3):

You can't create an instance of an interface, but you can create an instance of a class that implements an interface.
As long as the object you're adding, is an instance of a class that implements `ITestItem` it can be added to your `List<ITestItem>`

Example:

```
public class SomeListItem : IListItem
{

}

var item = new SomeListItem();

testList.Add(item);
```

Alternatively (and possibly more likely) there will be a class that already implements `IListItem` somewhere within the code that has `IlistItem`

Comment: it's not possible for me to create a new class that implements the interface :(

Comment: Not sure why you've downvoted this answer?

Comment: "Beside, there is no class that implements the interface ITestItem" There´s no such class `SomeListItem`.

Comment: @Alex not me, I didn't

Comment: @anhtv13 Why is it not possible to create a new class that implements the interface?

Comment: @HimBromBeere - which is why I've stated to CREATE a class... it's the only way!

Comment: @HimBromBeere he says there is no class that implements the interface, why not write one?

Comment: Precisely! OP says there's no class that implements the interface. The answer is to write one. Not downvote the answer telling him to write a class that implements the interface?!

Comment: @phuzi I have no permission to change my customer's code

Comment: In particular OP added a comment to your answer: "it's not possible for me to create a new class that implements the interface" So your answer doesn´t help, the only answer is: there´s no way to achieve that.

Comment: @anhtv13 but the class you write will be in your code not the customer's.

Comment: @anhtv13 you don't need to edit your customer's code. If you are able to create a list of that interface, you can implement it as a class.

Comment: @HimBromBeere as all the other ppl commenting here are stating, it is possible to create the a class implementing that interface... if the OP can create a List of it!

Comment: I can´t see your point. What does the fact if or if not OP *can* create a class has to do with any list? If OP can´t create a class for whatever reason there´s nothing he can do. That´s it.

Comment: `So, is there anyway to add a new item to ITestItem` - yes, by creating a class that implements `ITestItem` - hence, my answer!

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot instantiate an interface. You need to create a class that implements that interface.

Answer (score 0):

No, an interface is not instantiable. You need a class that implement your interface, and instantiate an instance of this class that you can then add to your list.